# JRuby installation gives Java path error

Tags: jruby

I have downloaded jruby-bin-ion 1.7.8 package and unzipped it in the C drive.
I have set the `PATH` and `JRUBY_HOME` environment variables. Java is installed and path and environment variables are set for Java. Java programs run well.

When I run `jruby -version` command from the command prompt, it gives me the following error:

```
Cannot locate Java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25;
```

Comment: From the same command line what does java -version output?

Comment: java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode, sharing)

Comment: ok, what does this return (exactly): for %i in (java.exe) do @echo.%~$PATH:i

Comment: when i put this line , it gives the result %~$PATH:i

Comment: what version of windows are you running

Answer (score 5):

Very late to the party here, but I had tried

```
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
```

and got the message

```
Cannot locate Java installation, specified by JAVA_HOME:
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"
```

The answer about semi-colons brought into focus the quotes might be causing the problem. And they were.

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
```

fixed my problem.
So, no quotes. No semi-colons.

Answer (score 2):

Set the environment variable correctly

```
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25"
```

No semi-colon if its only one value.